# sum (1 for x,y in zip (lista1,lista2 if x==y). Como se comparan los valores

Tags: python

Pregunta tonta pero estoy haciendo la siguiente interacción en paralelo en python:

```
myd = {'a':'primero', 'b':'segundo',
               'c':'tercero'}

z=sum(1 for x,y in myd.items() if x>y)

print(z)
```

Todo perfecto en la interacción, el problema es que no entiendo es esto:

```
Cuando:

x<0 imprime 3
x==0 imprime 0
x>0 imprime 0
```

Es decir que valores toman "x" y "y" ?

Yo pensaba que "x" siempre era 3 porque tomaba los 3 valores de los key del diccionario, y la "y" siempre era 3 porque tomaba los 3 valores del value.

Aquí hay otro código parecido pero con listas:

```
p = [1,1]
s = [2,1]

z=sum(1 for x,y in zip(p,s) if x==y)

print(z)
```

Imprime esto:

```
Cuando :
x<y =1
x== y = 1
x>y = 0
```

Es decir que valores toma "x" "y"  y como los compara para dar esa salida.

Comment: Hola. ¿Pudiste comprender lo que preguntabas? Saludos

Comment: Si. me ha servido. Pero sigo muy confundido en asignar variables a las cadenas. Por ejemplo : --- x,y = 'ab'  imprime a b, ---. . pero: ---x,y = 'a' , 'b'  tambien imprime  a b , a pesar de estar separados como elementos diferentes.. . . . Es mas , no se porque si hago esto : y= ['a','b'] imprime ['a','b'] con corchetes y comillas.  Me tiene bastante confundido las cadenas. Pero creo que eso sera otra pregunta. Me ayudaste mucho.

Comment: Sí. Estás confundiendo lo que llaman múltiple asignación con tipo de dato string y tipo de dato lista. He editado la respuesta y he añadido un pequeño apartado. Aún así, cada tipo de dato es un "mundo" y se haría muy larga la respuesta por lo que, sí, lo mejor es que agregues otra pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias adrian. Me ayudaste a entender intuitivamente las asignaciones multiples. No tenia idea que  'ab' era lo mismo que 'a' , 'b' , yo lo sabia por experimentacion . Espero debes en cuando me des ayudas con algunas dudas que me surjan. Saludos.

Comment: Me alegra haber sido de ayuda. Para eso estamos. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a modificar el código de la primera parte donde usas el método `items()`.

**De**:

```
myd = {'a':'primero', 'b':'segundo',
               'c':'tercero'}

z=sum(1 for x,y in myd.items() if x>y)

print(z)
```

**A**:

```
myd = {'a':'primero', 'b':'segundo', 'c':'tercero'}

for x,y in myd.items():
    print("El valor de x es: ", x)
    print("El valor de y es: ", y)
```

1. ¿Qué valores toman x e y?

**Ejecución**:

```
$ -> python3 items.py 
El valor de x es:  a
El valor de y es:  primero
El valor de x es:  b
El valor de y es:  segundo
El valor de x es:  c
El valor de y es:  tercero
```

El método de diccionario `items()` lo que hace es devolver una lista con un conjunto de tuplas donde cada tupla con dos elementos indica clave, valor. Por lo qué lo siguiente:

```
myd = {'a':'primero', 'b':'segundo', 'c':'tercero'}
print(myd.items())
```

**Devuelve**:

```
dict_items([('a', 'primero'), ('b', 'segundo'), ('c', 'tercero')])
```

De allí a que se pueda iterar con un for cogiendo la clave y el valor. ¿Qué sucede? Que la condición en el if está comparando la posición de los caracteres unicode. Por ejemplo:

```
a = 'segundo'
b = 'primero'

print("Punto unicode a: ", ord(a[0]))
print("Punto unicode b: ", ord(b[0]))

if a < b:
    print("a menor que b.")
elif a > b:
    print("a mayor que b.")
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 a.py 
Punto unicode a:  115
Punto unicode b:  112
a mayor que b.
```

Al estar en la posición 112 lo calculado con el método `ord()` en la variable b (primer caracter de la string) con la posición 115 de la variable a, el if se evalúa de esa forma.

Más info:  [Método ord()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord)

---

Con el segundo apartado, cambiaré el código.

**De**:

```
p = [1,1]
s = [2,1]

z=sum(1 for x,y in zip(p,s) if x==y)

print(z)
```

**A**:

```
p = [1,1]
s = [2,1]

for x, y in zip(p, s):
    print("El valor de x es: ", x)
    print("El valor de y es: ", y)
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 items_zip.py 
El valor de x es:  1
El valor de y es:  2
El valor de x es:  1
El valor de x es:  1
```

En este caso el método de listas `zip()`, que te devuelve un objeto (si le haces print el resultado será algo como esto:  `<zip object at 0x7f316fabbbc8>`) también posee una lista con tuplas.

**Si pasamos por el método list el objeto zip**:

```
p = [1,1]
s = [2,1]

print(list(zip(p, s)))
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 items_zip.py 
[(1, 2), (1, 1)]
```

Cada tupla en la lista son un par de elementos donde coge un elemento de la primera lista y un elemento de la segunda lista. En este caso ambos son int por lo que podrás hacer uso del if de forma correcta y comparar elementos

---

Por último, con el tema de **asignación múltiple** o **multiple assignment**:

Es totalmente válido asignar de la siguiente forma:

```
>>> a, b = 'ab'
>>> print("La variable a es de tipo:", type(a), "y equivale a:", a)
La variable a es de tipo: <class 'str'> y equivale a: a
>>> print("La variable b es de tipo:", type(b), "y equivale a:", b)
La variable b es de tipo: <class 'str'> y equivale a: b
```

En este caso, digamos que se hace un "split" de lo que hay luego de la igualdad. Para poder asignar con "igualdad" cada letra a cada variable. Tienes que tener cuidado con este tipo de casos porque podría ocurrir lo siguiente:

```
>>> a, b = 'abc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Este **ValueError** viene dado porque intentas asignar 'a', 'b' y 'c', a solo 2 variables. ¿Dónde asignarías la tercera? Error.

Este caso digamos que es un poco "especial" porque normalmente cuando haces asignación múltiple, se suele hacer separando por comas. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> a, b, c = 'A', 'B', 'C'
>>> print("La variable a es de tipo:", type(a), "y equivale a:", a)
La variable a es de tipo: <class 'str'> y equivale a: A

>>> print("La variable b es de tipo:", type(b), "y equivale a:", b)
La variable b es de tipo: <class 'str'> y equivale a: B

>>> print("La variable c es de tipo:", type(c), "y equivale a:", c)
La variable c es de tipo: <class 'str'> y equivale a: C
```

Un pequeño ejemplo adicional de [asignación multiple](https://apprimac.com/asignacion-multiple/) .

Finalmente, comenta que confundes lo siguiente:

```
y = ['a','b']
```

Y dices que y te imprime exactamente `['a', 'b']`.

Esto es normal. En este caso estás usando corchetes y el tipo de dato pasaría a ser ´´´lista´´´.

¿Por qué usé en el ejemplo anterior `type`? Porque este método te ayuda a encontrar el tipo de dato con el que estás trabajando. Antes trabajabas con `cadenas` o `strings`. Ahora pasaríamos a trabajar con listas (digamos que son como "`arrays`" en otros lenguajes de programación):

```
>>> y = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> print(type(y))
<class 'list'>
```

Tienes más información aquí:  [Listas en Python](https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/leccion3/tipo_listas.html)

Intenta entender cada tipo de dato que posee Python y se te hará mucho más fácil diferenciar todo esto.
Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Dices que _la condición en el if nunca se dará porque estás comparando strings con int_. En realidad se compara _strings_ con _strings_. Lo que pasa es que con las cadenas que se usan en el ejemplo siempre se cumple que `x < y`.

Comment: Sí, me fijé muy mal, no sé porque lo hice pensando que la key eran enteros. Modifico. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Por cierto, me ayudaste mucho con el metodo ord(). Sabia que por alli iban los tiros y por eso se podia evaluar entre dos caracteres a pesar de no ser numeros